# PHP: Youtube Require YouTube.php Occurs Error On Line 32

Tags: php, youtube

Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/content/90/9753290/html/Google/Service/YouTube.php on line 32

is the error message I am receiving, the GOOGLE API stuff I had gotten off GITHUB but I have no clue what is going on with this error message???

I heard from somewhere if I uploaded autoload.php and added require_once 'Google/autoload.php'; it would get rid of the error but still not success.

I was trying to follow the google tutorial for youtube to retrieve your own videos but the starting block is already holting my progress

Any help please?

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxx-xxx-xxx;
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx-xxx-xxx';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 13
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
```

http://www.sentuamessage.com/index.php?action=snapclipstest as we can see the error

Comment: there's a `'` missing in the 5th line `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxx-xxx-xxx;` (probably due to copy/paste error)

Comment: yea that is due to me editing the xxx-xxx-xxx error or else the ' ' does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Very Short Answer:

Add this to the top of your script and see if it works:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/google-api-php-client/src');
```

(changing `/path/to/google-api-php-client/src` to the appropriate path)

## Short Answer:

This error happens because the class `Google_Service` was not loaded which means that:

1. A file is missing (you didn't copy the library files properly)
2. The file is present but was not loaded (there's a problem in your autoload.php script)

## Longer answer:

Checking the [source code in the github repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), the error reports back to this bit of code in the [Google/Service/YouTube.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php) file:

```
class Google_Service_YouTube extends Google_Service
{
```

As you see, it's the `Google_Service_YouTube` class declaration which extends the class `Google_Service`.

`Google_Service` class is defined in [Goolge/Service.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service.php) file. So this file is not being loaded properly.

By checking your code...

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
```

..you're using the library's autoloader script but then requiring other files manually, which is strange (and you shouldn't need that)!

This probably means you didn't follow the instructions properly. [As stated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation):

> After obtaining the files, ensure they are available to your code. If
> you're using Composer, this is handled for you automatically. If not,
> you will need to add the location of the src/ directory inside the
> client library to the include_path, so that the PHP runtime can find
> the files

So, since you're not using composer, you need to add the library's path to php's include path.

I would, however, suggest that you use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install this library, [as stated in this library's documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation). This will take care of autoloading your files as well as installing any dependencies (currently none, but they might add some in the future).

Comment: right so I went on GITHUB and downloaded the zip file, uploaded it, edited the code to get rid of auto load and included in that top line with the path edited, I still though get the same error, if I try to use composer I wouldn't understand it :/

Comment: I readded in the auto load on top of everything you said and now it works